# Django admin login with credentials in URL

Tags: django

I am a newbie in Django. Basically what I am looking for is - I want users to click on a link and login into the admin site. Can the parameters be passed in the URL itself ?
Please help.

Comment: What you trying to do is insecure. You should avoid logging users this way. Anyway, here is [reversing admin urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own view on your website that will:

- get the credentials from your URL
- authentificate the user using *authenticate* and *login* functions from *django.contrib.auth* (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#auth-web-requests)
- and then redirect your user to the admin URL using django *redirect* function (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)

Comment: Clearly the way to go! Thank you okm / Patrice.

Answer (score 0):

Register Your admin panel with django .  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial02/#activate-the-admin-site

Change your `urls.py`  like

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
    from django.contrib import admin
    admin.autodiscover()

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        # Examples:
        # url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
        # url(r'^mysite/', include('mysite.foo.urls')),

        # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
        # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

        # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    )
```

Give the href as `<a href = "www.yoursitename.com/admin/">Click</a>`

You are done